# I/O performance comparison not confounded by caching

Tags: performance, caching, io, performance-testing

I want to compare the time performance of two different software programs, one single-threaded and the other multi-threaded, for loading a set of files from a (network) drive into memory. What's the best way to eliminate the (confounding) effects of caching from my comparison as much as possible? I have noticed that the first run of either program with a new set of files is much slower than the subsequent runs of the same program with the same file set. Is running each program at least twice with each file set and recording the time performance from the last run a reasonable way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Just so that I have got this right, you make a request to the software and the software brings the file to memory and returns some sort of response.

Given this, there might be two types of caching that might occur,

1) **software itself might cache the request**: you need to understand how the software is caching the request and vary the request path, querystring or header accordingly

2) **the in-memory cache** won't upload the file again unless it's a new file - if that's the case then you might want to set the TTL to zero and it's LRU cache then reduce the cache size small enough so that the cache rolls over before you perf test the file again.

Also most softwares responds with cache hit or miss information in the response so you might want to pay attention to that.

Hope this helps.